# Append javascript file into view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I created an application that based on ASP.NET Core .NET Framework.
I have a view and want to add javascript file on it and did as follow:

```
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
<input id="greet" value="Hello!" type="button"/>
```

I do not add to the layout template, because it is only for view specific.
The file structure looks as follow:
[image]

My problem is, when I start the application, then the javascript file `app.js` does not load at all, also `jquery.backstretch.min.js` file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should describe the problem. You haven't provided any description of that.

Comment: Sorry, I was out of my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

In your view

```
@section scripts {
       <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
}
```

In your layout

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**CSS**

in your view:

```
@section Styles {
    <link href="~/Content/contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

In your layour

```
@RenderSection("styles", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.js")"></script>
```

Browsers don't understand the meaning of ~